# Using extjs 4.2 grid as attendance management system

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I am looking to create an attendance sheet but not getting the magic idea for the same. Possible options for me[image]

1. Use grid but done know how to pass date values as grid column headings
2. Use table but don’t know how to edit the same. grid is editable component.

Please help me with the thought process

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `Ext.grid.Panel` is the component for this purpose. Grid conceptually more resembles database tables (fixed columns/fields repeated many times in rows/records) than spreadsheets (cells w/o prescribed purpose).

Also, grid has a lot of features like sorting, column re-ordering, column hiding that you would need to turn off for this purpose. Grid is just an overkill.

I would probably go with a custom table-like form with checkboxes. The form would be dynamically generated as employees can change and dates as well.

Comment: hmmm.. thanks Saki. But how can i create a dynamic form with extjs4

Comment: use ext.net ,it is easier :)